# Entity Framework DataContext enforces delete cascade even if it’s disabled

Tags: entity-framework, frameworks, entity, cascade, cascading-deletes

I have 2 tables with a many to many relation (Users  <-> Permissions):

```
modelBuilder.Entity<User>().HasMany(x => x.Permission).WithMany()
```

I disabled “delete cascade” from the many to many relation to get an exception if the permission is referenced by a user.

```
modelBuilder.Conventions.Remove<ManyToManyCascadeDeleteConvention>();
modelBuilder.Conventions.Remove<OneToManyCascadeDeleteConvention>();
```

The database schema is generated correctly. 
When I delete a permission (item) like following:

```
_dbContext.Entry(item).State = EntityState.Deleted;
_dbContext.SaveChanges();
```

the relation gets removed and no validation exception is fired.
However, when I delete the permission with pure SQL from the SQL Server Management Studio:

```
 DELETE FROM [Permissions]
 WHERE Id = 3
```

the exception is fired.

Note: I load all entities eager.

Has anyone an idea why the Entity Framework fires no exception and allows this operation?

Answer (score 0):

Problem found: If I load the data lazy the deletion work as expected.  Exception is fired:

```
 (The DELETE statement conflicted with the REFERENCE constraint....)
```

Solution: Pending